# What is the standard of determining whether someone understanding the concept?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language, concept

A typical example would be aphantasia, a group of people who can't imagine pictures in mind. That means they are unable to imagine concrete object like geometry and it's almost the only way to know those diversiform shape by imagining. Therefore they don't truly understand the concept.
I supposed to believe in my argument above but somehow I think it is a liitle strange but I can't tell where. So I post this naive thread here for help.

Comment: The standard must directly correlate to what's desired, which must be something more than the standard itself, and show differences in outcomes. It's like any experiment.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: It depends on the concept. The concept is simple, like addition. A person who can do addition. He understands **addition**; that's it. But if you ask about complex concepts like **differentiation**. People will have different intuitions about these concepts. **We can check the understanding of the concept based on its applicability.**

Comment: Kantian philosophy could answer your question. Symbol grounding is informing empirical meaning and transforming understanding capable of generalization which is critical as a non-reflex learning agent and unfortunately natural language as an abstract symbol system is extremely contextual *extensional* usage embedding and (multi) modal. Perhaps you need to examine and reflect upon your own *perceptual* symbol system entangled and *mirrored* in your embodied sensorimotors from a first person perspective to have a penetration, which ultimately hinges upon your specific aligned ethics framework…

Comment: @DoubleKnot care to elaborate? I don't understand the last half of your words

Comment: If you dwell in the common dualistic Cartesian theater sooner or later you'll become confused about the mechanism expressed in your titular question, that's where the extended-to-and-in-the-world [embodied cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition) as Berkeley rightly hinted *to be is to be perceived*. Modern neurosceince demonstrated [mirror neuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_neuron) proposed in simulation theory, and in the same sense there might be mirror symbols intensioned in body's sensorimotors...

Comment: @DavidGudeman Already renew my post.

Comment: 2 crucial links, one is the subtle difference btw an embodied symbol and a Cartesian mental picture or linguistic morpheme quale, whose difference should hint passively sitting and watching in a theatre cannot gain true understanding in the same way as reading a lot while not able to answer a lot people's different questions is a sure sign of no deep understanding of the read concepts. The other is the enactive sensorimotor's perceptual symbols at this level could refer to themselves by some interpretant per Peircian triadic semiosis acting as some machine *language* like reentrant circuits...

Comment: You seem to think that understanding requires insight or imagination. I don't think it does. In the same way I can reliably use a word without being creative.

Comment: But the meaning of word is grounded on the referent object, isn't it?

Comment: Obviously yes based on the traditional old metaphysics and common sense for the natural languages, however, not necessarily so at the reentrant neural signals machine language level since otherwise you'll get the typical homunculus-like infinite regression Cartesian problem while OTOH our body is physical and limited. Then the remaining homework for you is to bridge the self-reference and modification of the mirrored percept sequence of symbols with self-morality ethics...